# Syntax Error in INSERT INTO Statement on adding data

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm having problems with my add data codes, everytime I click the button for adding it says `Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement`. 
I've checked for the spelling of fields, designated textboxes for the fields, table name. What could be the problem these codes?

```
 If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        TextBox16.Text = DataGridView1.RowCount
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim SqlQuery As String = "insert into tblsched(id,time,day,room,professor,subject,students)VALUES ('" & TextBox16.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox12.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox13.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox2.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox3.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox10.Text.Trim & "');"
            Dim SqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
            With SqlCommand
                .CommandText = SqlQuery
                .Connection = con
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("Schedule Added", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Added")
            con.Close()
            datagridshow()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), which is probably 99.9999% chance the reason for your error message.

Comment: you need a space between "tblsched (" && ") VALUES" (otherwise it thinks tblsched is a function) In general when debugging mySQL, output the full query and try it in phpmyadmin. it will give you a more specific error

Comment: Ive found it out, it goes like this: [id], [time], [day], [room] - - - - - - like that. Thank you very much for the ideas though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As @danielml01 mentioned, it appears you are missing a space between ) and VALUES.  It appears that the semi-colon at the end of the statement is the standard syntax I am seeing, although I know that inserts without the semi-colon work for me.

Try:

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "insert into tblsched(id,time,day,room,professor,subject,students) VALUES ('" & TextBox16.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox12.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox13.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox2.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox3.Text.Trim & "','" & TextBox10.Text.Trim & "');"
```